# Beautiful Soup - Python

Tags: python

I was hoping to ask a pretty simple question. I have come across the below code and have not been able to find a decent explanation as to:

1. What exactly does the `.attrs` function do in this case?
2. What is the function of the `['href']` part at the end i.e. what exactly does that part of the code execute?

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("url")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
    print (link.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: [`.attrs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) returns a dict of all the attributes and values in the tag. `print(link.attrs['href'])` simply prints the value of the `href` attribute of that tag.

Comment: PS - Questions which ask for explanation of code are generally frowned upon. A question needs to have _a specific problem or error_. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Downvote: You clearly need to be familiar with the basics of HTML before you try to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go line by line after imports

- Load a url into variable called html
- Create BeautifulSoup object from html
- For every link in the object's "a" tags (it loops over html tags in the html, finds all `<a>` and loops over them)
- If the attribute of the tag has 'href' (`<a href="">` - href is an attribute, thatt's stored in the link's .attrs property)
- print to stdout the attribute that has key 'href' (it's a dictionary with `'href':'http://something'`)

The indentation is a bit wrong there, print should have be more indented than if

Comment: fantastic, thank you and apologies for the simplicity of the question!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to fetch this question it self and see:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/q/39308028/1005215")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

> i) what exactly does the .attrs function do in this code

```
In [6]: bsObj.findAll("a")[30]
Out[6]: <a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/39308028/beautifuelsoup-python">Beautifuelsoup - Python</a>

In [7]: bsObj.findAll("a")[30].attrs
Out[7]: 
{'class': ['question-hyperlink'],
 'href': '/questions/39308028/beautifuelsoup-python'}

In [8]: type(bsObj.findAll("a")[30])
Out[8]: bs4.element.Tag
```

If you read the [documentation](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=attrs#attributes), you will notice that a tag may have any number of attributes. In the element number 30, the tag has attributes 'class' and 'href'

> ii) what is the function of the ['href'] part at the end

```
In [9]: bsObj.findAll("a")[30]['href']
Out[9]: '/questions/39308028/beautifuelsoup-python'
```

If you look at the above output, you will see that the tag had an attribute 'href' and the above code fetched us the value for that attribute.